# JavaFX snapshot certain layers range in a StackPane

Tags: javafx

Assuming there are 3 layers in the stackpane. How can I just snapshot the overlaying result of layer no.2 and layer no.3?

Comment: I just realized I can create an inner stackpane inside that stackpane, then just snapshot the inner one. Is it good resolution?

Comment: If you want to take the result of overlaying layer 2 and layer 3, you need to put them together on a different node. So yes, your solution is viable.